# Magento 2.2 I want to add plyr.js for Vimeo video, I'm getting requirjs error and Class.extend is not a function, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, magento2.2, requirejs, video

```
Error 
1) Class.extend is not a function.
2)RequireJS
   Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (_, utils, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
3) I'm getting black screeninsted to Video.
----------
Here are my code
<div data-type="vimeo" class="js-player" data-video-id="143418951"></div>
require([<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl("plyr/plyr.js")?>'], function (plyr) {
   plyr.setup('.js-player');
});
```